# How to verify a toast message in selendroid

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, selendroid

I need to verify a toast message like "created successfully". I tried by using linktext. But its not working.Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use following code in your selendroid code

**waitForElement(By.partialLinkText("Your Toast message"), 4, driver);**

where first parameter is your toast message. Second parameter is Time duration in Seconds,third is driver.

Comment: Is there any way to capture the toast and print it?

Comment: I will try to capture and will update soon ..Please Vote for the answer so that it will be helpful to other also

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#DAAA" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello! This is a custom toast!");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show()
```

Comment: Using Selendroid automation tool, I need to verify the toast message